# 4 if statements in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to generate formula for 4 if statements? 
There is value to be tested in T26.

Here are conditions:

```
1 - 500 000             -> 500k$
500 000 - 1 000 000     -> 1M$
1 000 000 - 2 000 000   -> 2M$
```

Here is what has been achieved:

```
=IF(T26="";"";IF(T26>1;"500k$";IF(T26>=500000;"1M$";IF(T26>=1000000;"2M$";""))))
```

Comment: Reverse the order of the conditions.

Comment: Thank you sir! Maybe you can add it as an answer so we can mark this one solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `true` comparison wins, so in order to correctly work through a list of overlapping intervals you need to start with the one that does not overlap and work backwards:

```
=IF(T26>=1000000;"2M$";IF(T26>=500000;"1M$";IF(T26>=1;"500k$";"")))
```

If you don't want to be concerned with the order of intervals, you need to specify both lower and upper bounds each time:

```
=IF(T26="";"";IF(AND(T26>=1;T26<500000);"500k$";IF(AND(T26>=500000;T26<1000000);"1M$";IF(T26>=1000000;"2M$";""))))
```